# Handling game going to background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

My goal is to allow my game to handle temporary interruptions gracefully (phone calls,Siri, SMS, home button clicked). I am aware that the `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` and  `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` from the delegate.m file is necessary. However I have no idea how to accomplish this task. My game is running on a `NSTimer`, I also have a "score" timer, background music and a pause and play button.

I checked for answers but none and a clear cut explanation. I also saw unusual alternatives. i would like to know the best programing practice to get this done. I am a newbie to programing so a clear and precise explanation(with code) would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Are these timers in a game controller or spread out in different classes? Does your pause / resume function already deal with all of the timers?

Comment: What I always do is set a BOOL to true when it does resignActive and then in the NSTimer every time it loops check to make sure the BOOL is NOT true before running any game code. (But I am curious as to when you actually click the home button and close an app it seems to "stop"... I wonder how Apple does that, can we just simulate that code without the user actually exiting the app?)

Comment: Yes, they are in a game controller. My pause and resume button handles the all the timers, but how would I implement the pause/resume code into the appDelegate.m without getting an error? trying to implement the pasue/resume in the appDelegate.m results in the error "No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'pauseButton'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.m, post a notification on willResignActive: like so.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"willResignActive" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

Then, where needed, you can add an observer like below. Now, whenever the app leaves the foreground, that viewController's pauseButtonClicked method will be called.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pauseButtonClicked:) name:@"willResignActive" object:nil];
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer when it's no longer needed.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"willResignActive" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your pause button is linked to `-(IBAction)pauseButtonClicked {`

then just use:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {//or whatever method you are using
     [self pauseButtonClicked];
}
```

Comment: Presumably not everything is running in the app delegate and you want to observe the application notifications...

Comment: Yes, my pause button is linked to '-(IBAction)pauseButtonClicked' in my viewController.m, but am Allowed to add '[self pauseButtonClicked]' to my appDelegate.m file? I am getting an error. @AlbertRenshaw